# Visual hitches in SwiftUI when dragging an element in a view with lots of Buttons

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm developing a macOS application in SwiftUI for image annotation (keypoints). Basically, the user can add keypoints (circles) by clicking the displayed image and it can move them around by dragging them if they are misplaced. I noticed huge slowdowns and hitches when dragging keypoints.

I wasn't able to find the issue using the debugger so I tried to narrow down the problem by removing code until the issue disappears. I found a minimal example which reproduces the issue:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Keypoint: Identifiable {
    var x, y: Double
    let id = UUID()
}

struct KeypointView: View {
    @Binding var keypoint: Keypoint

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .offset(x: keypoint.x - 10, y: keypoint.y - 10)
            .gesture(move)
    }

    var move: some Gesture {
        DragGesture().onChanged { value in
            let pos = value.location
            keypoint.x = pos.x
            keypoint.y = pos.y
        }
    }
}

struct KeypointsView: View {
    @Binding var keypoints: [Keypoint]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            ForEach($keypoints) { $keypoint in
                KeypointView(keypoint: $keypoint)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct ButtonsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                Button("\(i)") { }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var keypoints = (0..<10).map { _ in
        Keypoint(x: .random(in: 0...600), y: .random(in: 0...400))
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                KeypointsView(keypoints: $keypoints)
                ButtonsView()
            }
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

This represents a view with some keypoints (circles) in the main area, controls at the bottom (buttons) and some text on the view side. Dragging any keypoint results in lots of visual hitches, the movement is not smooth. By commenting the `ButtonsView()` and the `Text()` in `ContentView()`, the issue disappears and the movement is smooth.

I tried to identify the issue using the SwiftUI and the Hitches debuggers and I found that there are many critical commits during dragging. However, this is not very informative and I cannot understand what causes the issue.

By experimenting, I noticed that the more buttons they are, the most hitches they are. Also, commenting only the `Text()` view results in a less critical slowdown. Replacing the buttons by other views (`Text`, `Rectangle`, ...) also removes the issue.

**Any idea on what is causing the issue or a workaround?**

---

#### Update

I found a workaround that works for this particular example, but not for my original application. It consists in wrapping the `KeypointsView`'s `ZStack` in a `GeometryReader`:

```swift
struct KeypointsView: View {
    @Binding var keypoints: [Keypoint]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                ForEach($keypoints) { $keypoint in
                    KeypointView(keypoint: $keypoint)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

**This brings back a very smooth visual experience. Does anybody knows how this works?**

Comment: your code everything runs smoothly with me, even on the simulator, even with 50 circles. .... sorry I overread macOS ! let me check again ...

Comment: can confirm issue on macOS!

Answer (score 0):

If you skip the text and VStack – **and give the buttons a fixed frame** then it works. Don't ask me why...

```
var body: some View {
//  HStack {
        VStack {
            KeypointsView(keypoints: $keypoints)
            ButtonsView()
                .frame(width: 600, height: 100)
        }
//      Text("Hello")
//  }
}
```